# How does install4j decide where in the registry to store the installation dirs?

Tags: java, install4j

I am observing some `instdir` keys stored in local machine, and some in current user:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\installations\instdir<app.id>
HKCU\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\installations\instdir<app.id>
```

Is that based on a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local machine keys are only writable with elevated privileges. If no "Request privileges" action has been executed, the current user keys are used.